# Certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root

Tags: ssl, visual-studio-2013, certificate

I'm working on a PowerPoint add-in project in Visual Studio. I've signed the project (Project Properties -> Signing -> Select from file -> Enter password) with a certificate. I then went ahead and installed the certificate to Trusted Root Authority on Local Computer (in the same dialog as before, click More details -> Install -> Install to Trusted Root).

Unfortunately, when building, VS reports that "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority". Really not sure where to go from here; the certificate is indeed to be found within the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities", so I don't understand why VS is struggling with it. Thoughts?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2012/08/17/a-certificate-chain-could-not-be-built-to-a-trusted-root-authority.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen but I checked this out earlier and the update is reported by Windows to not be applicable (I suspect the update is already done)

Comment: To ask the obvious: Can your Visual Studio access the internet?

Comment: Yes, it can. I did a little more digging  on your suggestion btw; I do in fact have the update installed.

Comment: You could try rebooting your machine.  Maybe it takes a reboot to load the new certs.

Comment: No clue what happened but it suddenly worked. Rebooted several times, now it's all good.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it correct if you want.

Comment: This is less of a solution than it is a suggestion. I rebooted twice and it suddenly just worked. No clue as to why. I'd follow Tim's suggestions above though (rebooting may not be the right solution for you).